# How to switch to Resharper Dark theme with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2019, rider

I'm using Resharper with VS 2019 and would like to use the Resharper dark theme. When using Rider I configured it during startup

(I'm using the left one)

[image]

Where can I use this theme in VS 2019? I installed the Resharper Extension and have an active license but I'm not able to find it in

> Options => Environment => General => Color Theme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable Color identifiers in ReSharper, go to `ReSharper`->`Options...`->`Code Inspection`->`Settings` and enable 'Color identifiers'

[image]